# Is it okay to just say "no action needed" if a post in the review queue has already been edited?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, review

My question is that when I use the **review** feature in **StackOverFlow** sometimes I face some new questions called **First Posts** which is already edited by someone else.
and 90% of the times, that someone has much more points than me. then I'll simply say that **No action needed**.

I would love to suggest to the guys who are in control of this matter that they might be facing a programming bug or logical bug.

if the programming bug then I hope they fix it. and if it's a logical one. I would just love them to check whether this post is already edited by another person with higher score before posting it in the review.

Comment: Your question is fine here, though I'm not entirely sure why you think this is a problem.

Comment: @AnnaLear because it's simply a bug. unless it's you guys wanted it to be like that. just passing by questions already edited and get more review points :)

Comment: If you want to file a bug report, ask a question, succinctly summarize the bug in the title, explain how you triggered what you think is a bug in the question, indicate what you think should have happened that didn't and apply the `bug` tag along with related tags (review, in this case). The devs will then look into it, and other users will see if they can reproduce it. It's like a 'living' bug tracker :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if the post was edited by a high rep user (perhaps to clean up grammar), it doesn't necessarily make it good or useful, so putting it through review still seems like a good idea.

I'm leaning towards calling this one "by design".

Comment: then, every post should be viewed more than one time. not some random posts. isn't it?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan The review queues target specific posts (like, say, first posts new users make). We do have to draw the line at some point - Stack Overflow alone now has millions of questions and answers. Reviewing all of them just isn't going to realistically happen.

Comment: okay, I see. but not convinced. anyway, your answer seems to be the most reasonable one. even that I still think it should be fixed :)
Regards.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Bear in mind that `/review` is an evolving work in progress, so your feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If a question has been edited by someone else to the point where you cannot see any problems with it, the system expects you to press the No Action button. This indicates that the post no longer needs attention, and takes it out of the review queue.

The reason the post is shown to you despite the edit is because all edits do not necessarily improve a post (vandalism, incorrect edits). Moreover, most edits do not fix *all* of the problems with a post. So a post still definitely needs to be reviewed after it is edited to see if it passes muster.

The behavior you are describing is not a bug, it is by design.

Comment: so, as long as the post no longer needs attention. why they showed it at the first place?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan It still needs attention until you review it and specify that it doesn't. The system can't automatically detect if a post is high quality; if it could, we wouldn't need review queues in the first place.